# Shapefile rotated after displayed on Bing Maps

Tags: shapefile, kml, coordinates, bing-maps

I took a country shapefile from [Thematic Mapping API | World Borders Dataset](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php).

Then opened it in QGIS and saved needed layer as KML file and took coordinates for displaying polygons.

```
var country = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon([[new MM.Location(35.360881805420263,46.286518096923942),...
```

In QGIS shapefile is showing correctly but on Bing Maps it is rotated and in another place.

What is the problem?

Comment: probably longitude and latitude coordinates are inverted in your Bing Map

Comment: definately looks like a case of coordinate inversion.

Answer (score 2):

The `Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude: number, longitude: number)` class requires latitude first, then longitude.

Ukraine is located at [46° North, 35° East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine#Geography).

You have the values reversed, so 35° North, 46° East points to the Iraq/Iran border.

**Reference:**

- [Map Control API Reference | Location Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427612.aspx)